# trouble with solrnet when swapping cores

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm using SolrNet.0.3.1 and SolrNet.Ninject.0.3.1 in an ASP.NET MVC 3 app pointing to a Solr 3.4 instance.

I'm using multiple cores so I can test out schema changes on a second core without breaking the app. Multiple cores are not the problem per se; the app happily uses "core-live" while I'm beating "core-ondeck" to death with dumb typos and tweaks to the schema.

Solrnet's service location is http://[server]:8983/[solr-instance]/ and defaults to core-live via the instance's solr.xml defaultCoreName setting.

```
# solrnet service location
http://[server]:8983/[solr-instance]/

# instance's solr.xml settings for multiple cores
<solr sharedLib="lib" persistent="true">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="core-live">
    <core name="core-live" instanceDir="conf/core0/" />
    <core name="core-ondeck" instanceDir="conf/core1/" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

After testing schema changes on the second core from Solr's browser admin GUI, I swap cores and the app should now use the core I just modified.

```
# swap cores so app uses modified schema and index
curl "http://[server]:8983/[solr-instance]/admin/cores?action=SWAP&name=core-live&other=core-ondeck"
```

Except solrnet doesn't take notice of the schema changes and, for example, blows up on a query because the field that was of type String in the old schema is now of type DateTime in the new.

```
[ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.]
   System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast) +6429224
   System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr) +12711129
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig) +129
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +522
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index) +44
   SolrNet.Impl.DocumentPropertyVisitors.RegularDocumentVisitor.Visit(Object doc, String fieldName, XmlNode field) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\DocumentPropertyVisitors\RegularDocumentVisitor.cs:48
   SolrNet.Impl.DocumentPropertyVisitors.AggregateDocumentVisitor.Visit(Object doc, String fieldName, XmlNode field) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\DocumentPropertyVisitors\AggregateDocumentVisitor.cs:37
   SolrNet.Impl.DocumentPropertyVisitors.DefaultDocumentVisitor.Visit(Object doc, String fieldName, XmlNode field) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\DocumentPropertyVisitors\DefaultDocumentVisitor.cs:39
   SolrNet.Impl.SolrDocumentResponseParser`1.ParseDocument(XmlNode node, ICollection`1 fields) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrDocumentResponseParser.cs:65
   SolrNet.Impl.SolrDocumentResponseParser`1.ParseResults(XmlNode parentNode) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrDocumentResponseParser.cs:50
   SolrNet.Impl.ResponseParsers.ResultsResponseParser`1.Parse(XmlDocument xml, SolrQueryResults`1 results) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\ResponseParsers\ResultsResponseParser.cs:41
   SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryResultParser`1.Parse(String r) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrQueryResultParser.cs:46
   SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryExecuter`1.Execute(ISolrQuery q, QueryOptions options) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrQueryExecuter.cs:309
   SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions options) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrBasicServer.cs:83
   SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer`1.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions options) in c:\prg\SolrNet\svn\SolrNet\Impl\SolrServer.cs:50
   Andornot.FhaPhem.Core.Search.SolrSearchOperations.GetResults(ISearchParameters searchParameters) in C:\svn\Client Projects\Fraser Health\PHEM\trunk\Web\Andornot.FhaPhem.Core\Search\SolrSearchOperations.cs:55
   Andornot.FhaPhem.Core.Search.SolrSearchOperations.Query(ISearchParameters searchParameters) in C:\svn\Client Projects\Fraser Health\PHEM\trunk\Web\Andornot.FhaPhem.Core\Search\SolrSearchOperations.cs:29
   Andornot.FhaPhem.Web.Controllers.SearchController.Results(Nullable`1 id) in C:\svn\Client Projects\Fraser Health\PHEM\trunk\Web\Andornot.FhaPhem.Web\Controllers\SearchController.cs:77
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +118
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826410
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826410
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +825632
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

How do I refresh solrnet's understanding of the schema on the fly, in a way that would work with core swapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an analogous situation, using tools that are probably more familiar:

You have a relational database (let's say Microsoft SQL Server) with a table "Person" with a field "data" of type varchar. In your code, you access this table through an ORM (NHibernate or EF, doesn't matter), where you have a class `Person` with a property `data` of type `string` in C# .

Now you edit the table's schema with SQL Server Enterprise Manager, and change the datatype of the field "data" to datetime.

Unless you update your code too to reflect this schema change, your code will break.

This is exactly what's happening in your case, except with Solr instead of a relational database, and SolrNet instead of an ORM. You're trying to get a date from Solr into a string property.

Solutions:

- Update your code to reflect the changes in your new schema.
- Switch to [SolrNet fully loose mapping](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping#Fully_loose_mapping). Not really recommended, it will probably blow up anyway with a change like that.

Comment: Thank you to both you and @PaigeCook! I assumed (for no reason) that solrnet would treat a field value according to the field map property type I set in my map regardless of the field type set in the schema, but solrnet actually parses the response field values as intelligently as possible? It's not doing that from its knowledge of the schema, is it? Because I could create any kind of crazy field type in there. Why parse response fields independent of any reference to my field map? Just curious.

Comment: @Peaeater : sorry, I don't really understand the question... a DateTime is a DateTime and a string is a string... how would you solve the analogous SQL/ORM problem ?

Comment: In the SQL/ORM analogy, the data type mapped by the ORM is dependent on a limited number of known SQL data types. But when solrnet infers a .NET type from a solr schema field, it must make a less educated guess at what that data type is, musn't it? Thinking that, I made an erroneous assumption that the field map I made might *drive* the mapper. Instead, I now understand that solrnet acts more like a standard ORM, and my field map does not influence its interpretation behaviour.

Comment: @Peaeater : SolrNet reads the Solr data type directly from the response, not from the schema (this doesn't make any difference in this case, I know). Solr has a few well-defined field types it uses in its output, i.e. it's not untyped: bool, str, int, float, double, long, arr, date. Having said that, you can always override the field parsers in SolrNet and make them behave however you want.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue is related to how you have your mapping setup in SolrNet. If you are changing the field type in your Solr schema, you will need to make the same corresponding change in your SolrNet mapping.

In order to allow SolrNet to work with on the fly schema changes, you will need to implemetn one of the following:

1. Follow the "Fully loose mapping" section defined in the [SolrNet Mapping documentation](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping).
2. Dynamically change your SolrNet mapped class when the schema has been changed to a new mapped class that matches the new schema.

The first option will probably be the easiest way.

Comment: I think I'll just leave all SolrNet questions on stackoverflow to you from now on :)